# Assign a username and password to specific users

Tags: private

We need a public section to our site and a private section. For the private section we would like to assign a username and password for each user that is NOT their Wordpress username/password. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. I would recommend you edit to clarify a number of things. Is the "private section" part of WordPress or something else? Are the users WP users (sounds like they are)? Are they coming to the private section from WordPress (if it's not part of WordPress)?  These are just some suggestions in terms of clarification - but really, you just need to be a little more descriptive of (1) what you're looking to do and (2) what you may have already looked into.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several possible ways to do this. The easiest method is probably to use Basic HTTP Authentication using a .htaccess and .htpasswd file. Here's a site that will [generate these for you.](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/) You can create separate usernames/passwords and then drop these files in the private folder. There are several guides and tutorials for this including [here](https://cets.seas.upenn.edu/answers/auth-htpasswd.html), [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04), and [here](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/set-up-basic-authentication-in-apache-using-htaccess-on-centos-7/).

Comment: Hi Zaack, Adding htpasswd will disable public access, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Akshat, the users question referred to adding a username and password for a private section of the website. As I stated, this can be done by placing htaccess/htpasswd in any subfolder to make that subfolder private.